# AND, OR, or XOR Assembly Language MASM X86 IRVINE

Tags: algorithm, assembly, x86, masm, irvine32

In sentences not code, I just need an explanation. How do you write the commands to change capital X to lower case x

Comment: Look at an ascii table. You will see the difference is 32. So you can just add 32. Accidentally, this is also a single bit difference so you can turn this bit on using bitwise OR. Also, you can toggle it with XOR and clear it with AND.

Comment: Although I agree with @Jester, one thing I'll mention is that it would be a good idea to check if your character is in the range of capital 'A' and capital 'Z' and if it is -  bitwise OR it with 32 (decimal). I only mention this because I don't know the context of the actual problem.

Comment: The title is a bit misleading or it is just me?

Answer (score 1):

If you will take a look at [ASCII table](http://www.ascii-code.com/), you will see that capital letters start from 65 to 90 and small letter start with 97 to 122. The difference between numbers is always 32.

So all you need to do is to add 32 to the `ord` of your value.

Comment: This works because the all the upper-case ASCII letters have that bit cleared, and the lower case letters all have that bit set.  You'd have to `add reg, 32`, rather than `or reg, 32`, if the alphabet crossed a 32-position alignment boundary, so some uppercase letters had the bit set and some didn't.  So your answer is correct, but your reasoning for why it works isn't sufficient.

Comment: @PeterCordes : I may be mistaken but he did suggest `add 32`. Possible confusion might be the use of _ord_. Don't think he meant `or` operator, but the ordinal (basic/pascal function?). I could be wrong.

Comment: @MichaelPetch: you're right, I was semi-skimming and read it as `or`'d, as in `or` 32 with your value.  Perl is one of the many dynamically typed languages that uses `ord` / `chr` for mapping between integers and ASCII/other-encoded characters, so I'm familiar with the terminology.  I was just thinking `or` because that's how normal people do it (once it's known that a character is a letter), like Jester's comment said. :P

Comment: @PeterCordes : You can tell I skipped the Perl fad ;-)